# One TCPSocket, two threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, asynchronous, tcpsocket

I need to implement a listening loop for `TCPSoket` client which will not block sending data to the same socket.

The approximate structure is so:

```
class SocketWrapper
  def initialize
    @messages = []
    @socket = TCPSocket.open('192.168.0.25', 2000)
    Thread.new do
       loop do
          @messages.push @socket.read
       end
    end
  end

  def send_message(msg)
    @socket.write msg
  end

  def read_messages
    @messages.dup
    @messages.clear
  def
end
```

Is it everything ok with this structure?

I need to implement two strategies here:

1. response = send_request(request_data)
2. listener - when incoming data is not a response for my request, but asynchronous data which I have to listen to.

Comment: Keep in mind that `@socket.read` is a blocking call and in most cases will wait until you close socket from the other end. If it's not what you want send length over the socket and use `read(n)`. And use `Queue` as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Does it mean that when socket waits for incoming data in one thread, it won't be able to send data in other thread? Are there some client socket events to subscribe to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has a class especially designed for that - [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html):

```
class SocketWrapper
  def self.instance
    @inst ||= self.new
  end

  def initialize
    @messages = Queue.new
    @socket = TCPSocket.open('192.168.0.25', 2000)
    Thread.new do
       loop do
          @messages << @parse_message.nil? ? @socket.read : @parse_message.call(@socket.read)
       end
    end
  end

  def parse_message(&block)
    @parse_message = block
  end

  def send_message(msg)
    @socket.write msg
  end

  def read_messages
    result = []
    begin
      while message = @messages.pop(true)
        result << message
      end
    rescue ThreadError
      #raised if queue is empty
    end
    result
  def
end
```

In initializers:

```
SocketWrapper.instance.parse_message do |raw|
  JSON.parse(raw)
  # or any other awesome thing with raw
end
```

In controller:

```
SocketWrapper.instance.send_message('blah blah blah')
```

Comment: Ok, I've built the class, put it into initializer so it can start at application startup, but how to call it's `send_message` method - how to refer to class instance? Variable assigned in initializer has been left in initializer and is out of scope.

Comment: Depending on your architecture, you can put it in a shared repository or even set it as a class member inside `SocketWrapper` - something like `SocketWrapper.current`

Comment: `def self.instance
      @@instance
    end

    def self.init_instance
      @@instance = SocketWrapper.new
    end`
 
SocketWrapper.instance is always nil. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you call `SocketWrapper.init_instance`? You don't need `@@` - `@` is enough

Comment: The problem was a probable name conflict in `@@instance`. Replaced to `@@inst`. And yeah, you are right, @ is enough.

Comment: And how to subscribe some external code to socket.read loop 'message appeared' event?